# NSUserDefaults: Updating data in plist

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am saving app preferences using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, inside it there are a few items, one of which is an array filled with dictionaries. I want to delete first item in that array, so I try something like:

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:accounts] removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

this does remove array item at index 0, but it doesn't update the plist file. But, when I do

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:accounts];
```

it removes all items AND updates the plist file. Why doesn't the first line save data to plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSMutableArray *Arr=(NSMutableArray *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"YourKey"];
[Arr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:Arr forKey:@"YourKey"];
```

Comment: thanks. this also works for line 1: `NSMutableArray *Arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:accounts] copyItems:YES];`

Comment: This is not safe. Objects returned from NSUserDefaults are explicitly documented to be immutable. In practice, in this specific case and some others, it isn't, but that is an implementation detail and taking advantage of it can lead to very odd bugs. Treat *all* returned objects from defaults as immutable.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states that values returned from `NSUserDefaults` are immutable. I take that to mean that if you retrieve a value (via `objectForKey:` for example), then modify that value, the change won't be persisted back through to the user defaults. You'll need to persist the change yourself via `setObject:forKey:`.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve using stringForKey: will be immutable.

Although what's really odd about this is the following appears to work... (But doesn't persist the change).

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@{@"hello" : @"1234"}, @{@"bye" : @"aoeu"}] forKey:@"accounts"];
  // Outputs both dictionaries
  NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accounts"]);
  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accounts"] removeObjectAtIndex:0];
  // Outputs only 1 dictionary
  NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accounts"]);
```

Comment: answer above did it. what's also weird is that if I delete item 0 (as I originally did), and then re-save another irrelevant key/value pair to plist - it also saves my short array!

Comment: That behaviour seems like a bug to me. It seems too inconsistent to be intentional.

Comment: Returned values from NSUserDefaults should be treated as immutable, even if behind the scenes they might not be. Consistency is not even a little guaranteed if this is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I found that that avoids initiating an array:

```
//do whatever with [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:randomValue forKey:randomKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```